# How to track a running object in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I have forked a Tensorflow.js code which essentially detects a variety of objects using a webcam video. I would like to know, if there is a way to track the moved distance ( X and Y coordinates) of specific objects like humans within the webcam to calculate their speed.

The most important thing for me right now is, to give every detected human, a unique ID. So that i can use that ID to store the object's coordinates in an array, for example:

```
let speed = { ID: 1, xVal: [1,2,3,4], yVal: [2,3,4,5] } // this code works fine and gives the predicted image an ID
```

The problems here is, the code breaks down the video into image frames and predicts every object in every image frame independently. So if i give a predicted object an ID for example ID = 1,

The predicted element will have an ID which is equal to 1. But that id will be lost whenever a new image frame appears, the code will predict again and the new image frame will lose all the IDs.

```
if(prediction.class == 'person'){
   prediction.id = 1; 
} 
// this code gives the predicted human object an id equal to 1. what i want is to give every human a unique ID. 
// Let's say the camera detects 5 people, i want each of them to have a unique ID 
// so that i can track their moved distance.
```

Here is a demo which shows the code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/z364noozrm .

Here is the tutorial i got the code from: https://hackernoon.com/tensorflow-js-real-time-object-detection-in-10-lines-of-code-baf15dfb95b2 .

Comment: Tracking is different from detection. The code you showed are detecting objects in the video. From there to do tracking, which means to keep the same id for the same object is not trivial. Granted if in the video, you have a single object detected, the detection becomes a tracking. But if not, you will need further processing comparing the detected boxes to see if they match somehow

Comment: what do you think of tracking.js library can it fit my needs. I'm thinking of creating boxes in the canvas and tracking the objects using sophisticated collision detections.

Comment: I haven't used tracking.js myself. You can give it a try and see if it suits your need.

Comment: any success yet?

Comment: @John it is hard to recognize, track and give ID to multiple objects in tensorflow.js. Instead i used other solutions.

Comment: @Axmednuur what other solutions?

Comment: @John i used paid solution that uses TensoFlow  and python. But if you have the solution for this i will happily accept it and upvote it.

Comment: I used a solution based on proximity, so it's not very accurate. This was more of an exercise for me and i'm happy with the current result